# Is there a way to use getall() to fetch only some properties in the data?

Tags: indexeddb

say my data stored in db is as follow:

```
key1 : {a:1,b:1,c:1}
key2 : {a:1,b:1,c:1}
```

is there any way I can use getAll() to get only the property `c` in each piece of data? sort of how to get the data in a column in sql database. I understand using cursor could achieve this, but the performance is nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an index on `c` and then use `getAllKeys`. Adding an index has performance implications as well, though.

Comment: somehow it doesnt return the actual value, but gives all the primary key path of the  key

Comment: `objectStore("foo").getAllKeys` will give you primary keys, but `objectStore("foo").index("bar").getAllKeys` will give you index keys.

Comment: My previous comment is actually wrong, you're right it does give primary keys. In which case I guess there is no way to do this, except for the primary key.